# Android AppCompat Overlay toolbar hides behind the widget

Tags: android, overlay, toolbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to make my toolbar/actionbar transparent. I can see a transparent toolbar but it hides behind the widget loaded by the fragment. The widget is a carousel of images. So when the image flip, I can see the toolbar below it. This is my App theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#19b333</item>
    <!-- ActionBar Theming -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

This is my ActionBar theme.

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And this is my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

This is my activity_drawer layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".activity.DrawerActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.fragment.SidebarFragment"
        android:id="@+id/sidebar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sidebar_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sidebar" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the toolbar after the content container.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```